# Audacity v2.1.2 hangs almost instantly when recording second track (overdubbing)

Tags: 17.10, alsa, audacity

- Open Audacity
- Record a few seconds of audio and press stop.  This works fine.
- Start recording again.  In a fraction of a second, the recording stops on its own (recording button is un-highlighted, stop button disabled).

Sometimes Audacity hangs.  Sometimes the new track never even appears.

If running audacity from the command line, this appears there at the moment of the problem:

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:8306:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
Expression 'err' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 3355
Expression 'ContinuePoll( self, StreamDirection_In, &pollTimeout, &pollCapture )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 3896
Expression 'PaAlsaStream_WaitForFrames( stream, &framesAvail, &xrun )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 4274
```

Even if not running from command line, this appears in /var/log/syslog at that moment:

```
Dec 16 10:37:52 myDesktop audacity.desktop[4765]: ALSA lib pcm.c:8306:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
Dec 16 10:37:52 myDesktop audacity.desktop[4765]: Expression 'err' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 3355
Dec 16 10:37:52 myDesktop audacity.desktop[4765]: Expression 'ContinuePoll( self, StreamDirection_In, &pollTimeout, &pollCapture )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 3896
Dec 16 10:37:52 myDesktop audacity.desktop[4765]: Expression 'PaAlsaStream_WaitForFrames( stream, &framesAvail, &xrun )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 4274
```

I've used Audacity for a bunch of other stuff and it works fine for that.  It's just not overdubbing.

## Didn't work

```
env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=30 audacity
```

## Versions

```
$ uname -a
Linux myDesktop 4.13.0-19-generic #22-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 4 11:58:07 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ apt list audacity
Listing... Done
audacity/artful,now 2.1.2-2 amd64 [installed]
```

Comment: Can you include in your question the output of `uname -a` and the output of `apt list audacity`

Comment: @CharlesGreen I added a "Versions" section with the commands you requested.

Comment: I can't duplicate your problem in my computer, although I suspect that you may have a different mix of programs than I.  What else in your system might be accessing 'alsa', 'jack' or 'pulse'?

Comment: @CharlesGreen Banshee.  System sounds (the little drum noises when you make a mistake).  USB microphone.  I don't know what else there could be.

Comment: Just a suggestion, because I don't have any real answer, stop banshee and unplug the USB microphone.  Do `pulseaudio --kill & pulseaudio --start` and seeif the problem remains.  You might also `mv ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/pulse.old` between the start and stop commands, to see if the local config file has something bad in it.

Comment: @CharlesGreen Thanks so much for your help. I tried killing pulseaudio, still had the problem.  Restarted pulseaudio.  Same issue.  See my answer below for what seems to have fixed it.

Comment: simply killing (without restarting) pulseaudio fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had edited /etc/pulse/default.pa to work around an issue with an earlier version of Ubuntu.  I had manually remade the edit after updating to 17.10:

```
load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0
```

So I changed it back to:

```
load-module module-udev-detect
```

Then I rebooted and everything worked fine.  No idea if that was it, or the reboot or what.